# should be only one Header in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

i   have   to    format    an    excel    sheet. it    contains   multiple    of    empty   rows,   haeders   repeated    after    several    rows. New    at    vb    script    and   this    type   of   excel    work.   how    can    i do   this.    can    some   one   help   me   in    macro   coding    of   this??? here   is   the   snapshot

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your data? It would be much easier to suggest then :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout here is the snapshot.

Comment: Are you refering to `Vendor Name` as a Header?

Comment: vendor name, check date and check amount.

Comment: Please add "@" like you did in your previous comment else I'll not come to know that you are addressing me. If your headers always start from a particular row(Ex-4 above) then check for all 3 headers using `.Find` and then delete the rows. Once that is done, you can either use Autofilter to delete the blank rows  or worksheetfunction `CountA` to identify the blank rows and then delete it. You might want to give it a try and then post the code that you tried and we will take it from there? Link which you may find helpful. http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle a project with a for/next loop.
You can get the total number of lines in the report so you know when to stop looking for things to format. You can make any sort of test you want in the loop with if and end if statements.
Here is an example that changes the format of any data that is in the first column.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Format_Report()

Dim Nbr_of_Sheets As Integer
Dim LastLine_Data As Long
Dim Loop_Ctr As Long
Dim LastLine_Plug_Code As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Nbr_of_Sheets = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

Sheet1.Select  ' Always select sheet 1 no matter what the name
Range("A1").Select
LastLine_Data = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For Loop_Ctr = 1 To LastLine_Data
    If Cells(Loop_Ctr, 1).Value <> "" Then

        With Cells(Loop_Ctr, 1)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Name = "Arial Black"
            .Font.Size = 14
        End With

    End If
Next Loop_Ctr
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```